# Error during building goLang program using Fyne GUI

Tags: go, fyne

"package command-line-arguments is not a main package"

This error showing when trying to build my go project using fyne gui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `“main”` tells the Go compiler that the package should compile as an executable program instead of a shared library. The main function in the package “main” will be the entry point of our executable program. When you build shared libraries, you will not have any main package and main function in the package.

Use `package main` in place of the package you have created

Comment: Actually, I was trying some sample projects from GitHub and it had  "package clock" in the place of "package main". If I am naming it "package main", it's not executing saying "main" is already declared (referring to other "package main" in the file folder).

Comment: It's very simple then the program uses the "package clock" and in the "main package" it will be called and then the package clock will get executed.

Checkout this tutorial

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packages-in-golang/#:~:text=Packages%20are%20the%20most%20powerful,of%20the%20other%20package%20programs.